# Vercel NextJS application not sending requests to Heroku express API

Tags: express, heroku, next.js, vercel

Im creating  a Next.js + express app with Vercel for nextjs and heroku for express server

> Localhost frontend and Localhost backend --> Working ✔️

> Localhost frontend and Heroku Hosted backend --> Working ✔️

> Vercel Hosted frontend and Heroku Hosted backend --> Not Working ❌ (404 error)

Can't find a reason why. I even removed the environment varibles and added just the backend server url on the frontend but still dosen't work. is there any options that I need to tinker with?

my nextjs server.js is as follows

[image]
I didn't add ant env variable on vercel so this should send to heroku. which is working on localhost nextjs sever

and backend server.js is as follows

[image]

Comment: How exactly it's not sending requests, what are the errors?

Comment: it shows the 404 error on sending a post (register) as not found but if i ran frontend server on my localhost it works ok. its just not working on vercel :/

Comment: The question would need more details on the app's code, probably a minimum reproducible solution as well. It's not clear what's the issue from just this description so far.

Comment: added the serverjs code on the question sir

Comment: Oof, I fear won't be able to debug it, but there's now a lot more info. Hope someone'd  pick it up. Meanwhile I'm surprised that next.js custom server works on vercel. I've seen in [next.js docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server) that `Note: A custom server cannot be deployed on Vercel.` although haven't tried myself. Maybe this could be the issue (but maybe not)

Comment: yes it does say it cant but server runs ok exept for backend calls ;/

Comment: using the full link in axios requests work ok in both localhost and vercel any idea?

Comment: Please make sure to post code and errors as text directly to the question (and [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551)), and [format them appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So by fiddling around the fix was very easy to miss out

the problem was vercel was not supporting custom servers and it is running the build after building the project so it runs the `next dev` script. so the server.js file won't be executed

so i made a folder `api` inside `pages` and added this code inside it

[image]

[image]

now it works

Comment: Please post your code directly to the post, no need of adding extra URLs that can become invalid in future.

Comment: ok I will do it in the future